# Bash script greater than or equal to if statement not functioning as expected

Tags: bash

The goal of this script is to get the output of my `getCpuTemp` function, which is currently `60.1`, and to send me a push notification via Pushbullet if the CPU temperature is over 70 degrees.

My script currently thinks that 60.1 is over 70, and I'm not sure why, is there something wrong with my if statement?

```
function getCpuTemp {
sensors cpu_thermal-virtual-0 | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $2}' | tr -d '+\°\C'
}
    
function sendPushNotification {
  curl --header 'Access-Token: <REDACTED>' \
       --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      --data-binary '{"body":"Server CPU Temp is very warm.","title":"WARNING: HIGH TEMP","type":"note"}' \
      --request POST \
      https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes
}
    
if getCpuTemp -ge 70; then
        echo "ABOVE 70"
        sendPushNotification
else
        echo "BELOW 70"
fi
```

Comment: `-ge` is an argument to the `test` command (also known as `[`). It's not bash syntax on its own

Comment: You might be thinking of `[ "$(getCpuTemp)" -ge 70 ]` -- the call to the `[` command is critical.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm now getting `./cpuTemp.sh: line 15: [: 60.7: integer expression expected`, but I'm also getting my echo of `BELOW 70`, so I think it's working?

Comment: The shell doesn't do floating point math. You need to strip off the decimal point and everything following it.

Comment: Thank you!

Changed my getCpuTemp function to `sensors cpu_thermal-virtual-0 | awk 'FNR == 3 {print substr($2, -2, length($2)-4)}' | tr -d '+\°\C'`, adding the `length` `awk` function, and it works!

Comment: @saturnSam all strings, arrays, and fields in awk start at position 1. When use `substr($2, -2, ...)` awk sees `-2` as an invalid value since it's impossible for a string to start at a negative index but instead of reporting an error and failing it assumes you meant `substr($2, 1, ...)` and does that for you instead. `substr($2, "fluffy bunny", length($2)-4)` would have the same behavior as `substr($2, -2, length($2)-4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CharlesDuffy already pointed out in comments, your use of `-ge` is invalid syntax plus bash doesn't understand floating point numbers but awk does and you're already using it so consider:

```
cpuTempIsOverOrEqual() {
    sensors cpu_thermal-virtual-0 |
    awk -v max="$1" 'NR == 3 {exit (($2+0)>=max ? 0 : 1)}'
}
    
sendPushNotification() {
  curl --header 'Access-Token: <REDACTED>' \
       --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
      --data-binary '{"body":"Server CPU Temp is very warm.","title":"WARNING: HIGH TEMP","type":"note"}' \
      --request POST \
      https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes
}
    
if cpuTempIsOverOrEqual 70; then
        echo "ABOVE OR EQUAL TO 70"
        sendPushNotification
else
        echo "BELOW 70"
fi
```

I'm assuming above that the output of `sensors cpu_thermal-virtual-0` has those characters that you're using `tr` to remove attached to the end of the 2nd field and, if so, you don't need to do that as awk will strip non-numeric characters from the end of any string you perform a numeric operation on, e.g. `+0`:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\nx %s+°C\nd\n' 60.1
a
b
x 60.1+°C
d

$ printf 'a\nb\nx %s+°C\nd\n' 60.1 |
    awk 'NR == 3 {print $2+0}'
60.1

$ printf 'a\nb\nx %s+°C\nd\n' 60.1 |
    awk -v max="70" 'NR == 3 {exit (($2+0)>max ? 0 : 1)}'; echo $?
1

$ printf 'a\nb\nx %s+°C\nd\n' 70.1 |
    awk -v max="70" 'NR == 3 {exit (($2+0)>max ? 0 : 1)}'; echo $?
0
```

If that assumption is wrong then edit your question to show us the output of `sensors cpu_thermal-virtual-0 | head -n 3` so we know what you're trying to parse.

Obviously pick whatever name you like for the function and change `>=` to `>` if you want the comparison to be `greater than` (as you say you want in your text) rather than `greater than or equal to` (as you have in your code with `-ge`).